# python's sys.settrace won't trace builtin functions

Tags: python

I've been using the sys.settrace function to write a tracer for my program, which is working great except that it doesn't seem to get called for built-in functions, like open('filename.txt').  This behavior doesn't seem to be documented, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if this is the expected behavior.  I am using Doug Hellmann's "trace_calls_and_returns" code from [here](http://doughellmann.com/2009/11/pymotw-sys-part-5-tracing-your-program-as-it-runs.html)  as my tracing function.

If I can't do this with settrace, is there any way to trace calls to open()? 
I don't want to use Linux's strace, as it'll run for the whole program (not just the part I want to trace) and won't show my python line numbers/file names, etc. 
The other option I considered was monkey-patching the open function through a wrapper, like:

```
import traceback, __builtin__
def wrapped_open(*arg,**kw): 
        print 'open called' 
        traceback.print_stack() 
        f = __builtin__.open(*arg,**kw) 
        return f 
open = wrapped_open
```

but that seemed very brittle to me.

Could someone suggest a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to trace compiled code imported into python, and [`open()` is not pure python, it's a C binding from CPython part of the Python distribution](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1481).

So the only way you'll have to trace within `open()` is to go for `strace` or an equivalent, but in any ways, get beyond what python can introspect of himself.